# async.waterfall doesn't render at the end

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, sequelize.js, waterfall

I tried to use async.waterfall to clean up my code. I've got two problems, here is my code.

```
async.forEachOf(req.files, (value, key, callback) => {
  imagesController.create(req, res, idCreation, req.files[key].filename, imageData[key].ext)
})  

async.waterfall([
  function(callback) {
   exhibitionController.create(req,res, idCreation, req.body.exhibitionName, req.body.galery, req.body.exhibitionBegin, req.body.exhibitionEnds)
 },
 function(exhibition, callback) {
  creationsController.findThisCreation(req, res, idCreation)
}],

function(err, creation) {
  if(!err){
      res.send(creation)
  }
})
```

With this code everything is set in my database, the datas are saved,
but the res.send(datas) at the end of the waterfall do not work. Instead my page with the form's still loading.

The other problem is for optimisation of the code: I tried to insert the forEach inside waterfall function but then all the datas are saved except my images.

I also tried to render inside the done of the forEach function, in fact I did all this stuff to wait for the images. But the problem is almost the same, the page does not render.

Comment: I believe `creation` will be `undefined` if you don't return anything in the final element of the `waterfall` function - might this be your issue?

Comment: creationsController.findThisCreation(req, res, idCreation) returns a result, its equivalent to findOne()

Comment: But you're not calling any `callback()` ?

Comment: i get it, i made callback(null, creationController etc.....), in fact now it returns me a result but is seems that it return me promises attributes as: isFullfiled: false, isRejected: false...i thought it will return the result of my request. I go further with this and try to access my datas.

Comment: i had to .then() my last result cause it returned a promise. So know it get my Creation entity with default datas filled but with the previous joined datas blank....(in the database everything is ok) what i expected from the waterfall is still not working perfectly...i'm going further.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve it but it was not a piece of cake....
i must admit that i'm not fully satisfied, i access to the Images and Exhibitions result only because i push them in the tab while creating them.
I was hoping that's the waterfall permit to wait that the jonction make itself before getting creation at the end of the waterfall,....
It's strange because when i'm accessing to the datas via the list of items page, my tabs are jointed with all the datas inside. And it is the same getter.
I have to work it more to find a real good solution.

here's my waterfall :

```
 async.waterfall([
  function(callback) {
   callback(null, creationsController.create(req, res, true))
  },
  function(creation, callback) {
    creation.then(function(crea){
         idCreation = crea.get('id');
         callback(null, exhibitionController.create(req,res, idCreation, req.body.exhibitionName, req.body.galery, req.body.exhibitionBegin, req.body.exhibitionEnds))
    })
 },
 function(exhibition, callback){
         exhibition.then(function(exhi){
             exhibitions = exhi;
             callback(null, async.forEachOf(req.files, (value, key, callback) => {
                    images.push(value);
                    callback(null,
                      imagesController
                         .create(req, res, idCreation, req.files[key].filename, imageData[key].ext));
          })) 
         })
 },
 function(images, callback) {
        callback(null, creationsController.findThisCreation(req, res, idCreation))
}], function(err, creation) {
  if(!err){
    creation.then(function(result){
       result.Images.push.apply(result.Images, images);
       result.Exhibition.push.apply(result.Exhibition, exhibitions);
       res.send(result);
    })
  }else{
      res.send(err)
  }
})
```